# scons: how to define command/target that only takes place during 'scons -c'?

Tags: command, execute, scons

Before building the targets I wish to create some directory structures, I know I can use:

```
env = Environment()
env.Execute('mkdir -p xxx')
```

But this will cause "mkdir -p' to be executed even when I do clean up:

```
scons -c
```

And the "env.Execute" will gets called.

I wish there's some command or target that's only taking place when I execute 'scons -c'

How to achieve that?
Thanks.

Comment: Are these directories which scons will build into? Because SCons will automatically create those in that case..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The -c option is a built in scons option and you can check if it was set with `GetOption('clean')`.

You could then call the commands conditionally based off the value of the 'clean' option. Here is an example:

```py
env = Environment()
if not GetOption('clean'):
    env.Execute('mkdir -p xxx')
else:
    env.Execute('echo "Cleaning up..."')
```

More info on the other built in options can be found here:
https://scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-user.html#sect-command-line-option-strings
https://scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-man.html#options